# "variance matrix is nonsymmetric or highly singular" in Stata; no SEs in table

Tags: regression, stata, poisson-regression

I get the above warning in Stata when I run a (clustered-panel pseudo-Poisson ML gravity-) regression.

Observations are pairs of countries and the regression includes dummies for each combination of country and year (2005-2012) as well as a lagged variable of one continuous independent variable.

If I drop either the set of dummies or the lagged variable, it works fine. But of course I'd like the dummies AND the lag to be in that regression...

Can anyone tell me what causes that warning and how I can work around it?

Results can be found here: http://pastebin.com/BieZCZJL
(note: I am aware that the dependent should not be logged)

Comment: Why not show results as well as sketch them? Also, look directly at the matrix.

Comment: It seems that for one pair you have only one observation. Including dummy is wrong in this case, since it explains all the variation in the cluster, hence estimated disturbance variance submatrix for that cluster is zero. Here is the suspected offending line: `IctcXyea_50_2007 |  -66.05867`

Comment: I've imported your output into R and got that there 4 country pairs that have only one year of observations, here are their ids: 50, 496, 682, 748. Remove them and try to rerun your calculations.

Comment: Ok then, I've converted my comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your output, you have 4 country pairs with only one observation. In this case including dummy variable is wrong, since it explains all the variation in the cluster, making the variance of disturbance zero. Removal of such cluster sometimes help.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question, but since this answer wasn't accepted I'd like to understand a little more. From the output, how did you establish which observations were causing a problem?

Comment: The data was supplied too. Also look at the comments above.

Comment: Ok, so "judging by your output" really means "judging from your data". Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can infer that some country pairs only have one data point by looking at the names of the variables.

Comment: Ah, very good point.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error for some regressions but occasionally with equivalent but different specifications Stata would provide Standard Errors suggesting some issue with Stata not my specification. My advisor suggested using a 2-step residualization method (see the answer by Tyrel Stokes [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358732/residualizing-dependent-variable-and-two-step-linear-regression)) when Stata gets overwhelmed.

Where the form of the regression is as follows: `Y = X + Other_Controls`

Step 1: Regress Dependent Variable (aka the Left Hand Side (LHS)) on All Controls Except Key Dependent Variable (X) for which you want standard errors (`reg y Other_Controls`). Then obtain the residuals (`predict LHS_residuals, residuals`)

Step 2: Regress Key Dependent Variable (X) (aka the Right Hand Side (RHS)) on the Other_Controls (`reg X Other_Controls`) then obtain the residuals from this regression (`predict RHS_residuals, residuals`)

Step 3: Regress LHS_Residuals on RHS_Residuals and you should get your standard errors for the key dependent variable of interest.

Comment: What you propose (even if it works; a quick reading of the CV answer that you cite notes that this type of approach might require a lack of correlation among the predictor variables) seems limited to ordinary linear regression. The question on this page is about a generalized (Poisson) linear model, which can have problems in estimating a coefficient covariance matrix via numerical methods. Ordinary linear regression, with a closed-form solution, shouldn't "overwhelm" any modern statistical system in that way unless the model has too many predictors for the number of cases.

Comment: It looks like you misread the link. Step 2 addresses the correlation among predictor variables - that's the point of the linked answer (only in the case of independent predictors can step 2 be skipped). I agree that it's weird but it does seem to happen - in my case weights, fixed effects, and clustered standard errors. For me knowing this technique would have been helpful, which is why I shared.